# Format for preg_replace to strip leading "1" and unwanted characters in phone number?

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code I am able to strip hyphens and parenthesis from phone numbers by using

```
preg_replace('/\D+/', "", $cell);
```

OR

```
preg_replace('/[ )(.-]/', "", $cell);
```

Two questions:

(1) Which of the above formats is best for removing ALL unwanted characters (,-,.,etc, as well as alpha characters.

(2) I also need to remove the leading "1" (country code for USA) if entered by user

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use only preg_replace? It might be just as easy to put an if( strlen( $phone_number ) > 10 ) { substr( $phone_number, 1 ); }

Comment: `\D` is your best bet- it's going to match everything that isn't a digit. Which is ultimately what you want right? Only digits?

Comment: @Jack, It makes sense to use preg_replace because it's needed for removing non-digits from the string, the '1' can also be included in the same regex.

Comment: @Godwin that is very true, but if he is looking to do it for only US based numbers, there is going to most likely be some other code going on to determine whether it is US or not. Since I am no RegEx guy, I put it in a comment instead of an answer :-)

Comment: @Godwin, by "best" I mean the format that would remove *ALL* unwanted characters from a phone number, including alpha characters

Comment: @Jack I will only be using US based phone numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to remove non-digits, but I would suggest using whatever method make the most sense to you, that is, which one seems most intuitive and easy to understand when you look at the code again months from now.

Your `\D` works just fine but adding `^1` will also replace the leading `1` you're looking for.

```
preg_replace('/^1|\D/', "", $cell);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. I would take a whitelist-approach instead: Remove everything, that is not a number, instead of removing everything, that is in the list a,

   ```
   /[^0-9]/
   ```

   your first expression `\D` should do the same. Any problems with that? If it works, keep it, because with the second (blacklist) approach you definitely miss characters. Either that, or your list must grow quite big.
2. Not a real answer, but definitely worth to mention: a country code is either `+X`, or `00X` (`+` is in fact just a shortcut for `00`), thus removing a leading `1` may lead to quite ugly unwanted behaviour. Must say, that I don't know exactly, how it works over there, but in germany a *local* phone number can start with (theoretical) *any* number (except `0` of course). This said you should take care to replace a leading `+` with `00` before removing unwanted characters (1).

Comment: I am using for US based customers only at this time for an sms application which requires the country code in a separate command. So I need to strip the country code out of the phone number and break it down to a series of 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

`$cell=preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $cell);

  $cell=preg_replace("/^1/","", $cell);`

Would Do it

Comment: Wouldn't `$cell=preg_replace("/^1[^0-9]/","", $cell);` work in place of using both commands above?

Comment: @user1322707, no, it would only replace non-digits which were followed by `1` at the start of the string. Adding `|` (OR) between the statements would have the effect of replacing them both.